# Let $K \subseteq L \subseteq M$ be two field extensions then, $K \subseteq M$ is algebraic iff $K\subseteq L$ and $L\subseteq M$ are both algebraic.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $K\subseteq L\subseteq M$ be two field extensions then,
$K\subseteq M$ is algebraic, if and only if, $K\subseteq L$ and $L\subseteq M$ are both algebraic.

Please how can I prove the sufficient condition

Comment: @JetChung your second assertion is not true. the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is an algebraic but not finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: It doesn't need to be finite to be algebraic you know

Comment: What have you managed, and where are you stuck? What related results do you already know?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom my apologies; only $[M:K]$ finite implies $M/K$ is algebraic and not the converse.

Comment: @JetChung no need to apologize! :) common mistake

Comment: Take an arbitrary element $z$ of $M$. It has a minimal polynomial over $L$. The coefficients of that polynomial are algebraic over $K$. This give rise to a finite extension of $K$ containing $z$. Conclude. (Finitely generated + algebraic => finite)

Answer (score 3):

For one direction, suppose $K\subseteq M$ is an algebraic field extension. Then every element of $M$ satisfies a polynomial with coefficients in $K$; in particular, every element of $L\subseteq M$ does too, and so $K\subseteq L$ is an algebraic extension. Additionally, polynomials over $K$ can be considered as polynomials over $L$ via the inclusion $K\subseteq L$, so every element of $M$ hence satisfies a polynomial over $L$ and thus $L\subseteq M$ is an algebraic extension.

For the reverse direction, the main point is that, if $E\subseteq F$ is a field extension, then $f_1,\dots,f_n\in F$ are each algebraic over $E$ if and only if $[E(f_1,\dots,f_n):E]<\infty$. This can be proved by induction on $n$ and the tower law; I will leave it as an exercise for you.

Anyway, this fact makes the desired result easy to show. Suppose $K\subseteq L$ and $L\subseteq M$ are algebraic, and let $m\in M$. Then $m$ is algebraic over $L$, so there is a polynomial with coefficients in $L$ satisfied by $m$. Let $l_1,\dots,l_n$ be these coefficients. Since $L$ is algebraic over $K$, each $l_i$ is algebraic over $K$, so $[K(l_1,\dots,l_n):K]<\infty$ by the result mentioned above. Also, $m$ is algebraic over $K(l_1,\dots,l_n)$, and so, again by the result mentioned above, $$[K(l_1,\dots,l_n,m):K(l_1,\dots,l_n)]<\infty.$$ By the tower law, this means $[K(l_1,\dots,l_n,m):K]<\infty$, and so, by one final use of the result mentioned above, $m$ is algebraic over $K$.